# How to handle exceptions that you didn't expect even thought it is declared on the documentation?

Tags: java, exception

When there are methods that throw exceptions and you know these exceptions will not be thrown, what should you do?

Many times I see people just logging the exception, but I wonder if there is a build in exception in java that means something like: "This exception should not have been thrown".

For example, imagine I have a code that calls `StaticClass.method(someObject)` and this method throws a `SpecificException` when `someObject` is not valid. What should you do in the catch block?

```
try {
  StaticClass.method(someobject);
} catch (SpecificException e) {
  // what should I do here?
}
```

Comment: That depends entirely on how critical that exception is to your program. Can you continue normally, or would it be better to just exit?

Comment: It would be better to just exit

Answer (score 1):

If when calling the method you know for sure that it will not throw an exception because of previous checks you should throw a `RuntimeException` wrapping the `SpecificException`.

```
try {
  StaticClass.method(someobject);
} catch (SpecificException e) {
  //This is unexpected and should never happen. 
  throw new RuntimeException("Error occured", e);
}
```

Some methods already throw a RuntimeException when they fail to perform their purpose.

```
//Here we know for sure that parseInt(..) will not throw an exception so it
//is safe to not catch the RuntimeException.
String s = "1";
int i = Integer.parseInt(s);

//Here instead parseInt(..) will throw a IllegalArgumentException which is a
//RuntimeException because h is not a number. This is something that should
//be fixed in code.
s = "h";
i = Integer.parseInt(s);
```

RuntimeExceptions don't require a try/catch block and the compiler will not be mad at you for not catch them. Usually they are thrown where something in your app code is wrong and should be fixed. Anyway there are cases where catching a RuntimeException is useful.